# Is "consist" really intransitive?

Tags: verbs, transitivity

I recently learned that I cannot use “be consisted of” because it is intransitive verb.

Example:

- Water consists of hydrogen and oxygen. (o)
- Water is consisted of hydrogen and oxygen. (x)
- Water is made up of hydrogen and oxygen. (o)
- Water is composed of hydrogen and oxygen. (o)

According to [grammar-monster](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/transitive_verbs.htm), an intransitive verb does not take a direct object; but, I think “consist of” takes direct object, which is “hydrogen and oxygen” from the above example.

I am wondering why “consist of” is intransitive verb despite of taking direct object.

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of transitive vs intransitive; it's that "consist" is a verb of its own, where as "make" (or "compose" etc) requires the passive "is made" with an auxiliary verb to make the meaning "having a structure of composition which includes ...".

Comment: You just have to learn that _consist of_ means _be made up of_ - the 'be' part is included in the meaning of the word.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! I'm not sure why someone downvoted your question. I think you did a good job explaining why you thought *consist*  takes a direct object. It is confusing because we rarely see a sentence like "Water consists" where nothing follows "consist".  Maybe it helps to notice that it is the water that "consists", not the hydrogen and oxygen. With a transitive verb like "The water erodes the land.", it is the land (or direct object) that is eroded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Consist" is intransitive. "Hydrogen and oxygen" is not a direct object in "Water consists of hydrogen and oxygen."

A direct object is called that because it is a noun phrase used ***direct***ly as the complement of a verb.

In the sentence, "Water consists of hydrogen and oxygen", the verb "consists" takes the complement "of hydrogen and oxygen". This is a prepositional phrase. "Hydrogen and oxygen" here is the object of the preposition "of", so it is not the direct object of the verb.

---

Passive constructions are a separate issue. A verb doesn't necessarily have to be transitive to be able to be used in a passive construction (for example, "It was taken care of" is not ungrammatical).

---

Note that "consists of" means "is composed of".